# Fuseki2 and TriX format

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena, fuseki

In Fuseki2, is it possible to request TriX XML (rather than RDF/XML) as a response format (for example when submitting a DESCRIBE query)? I've tried setting the Accept header to "application/trix+xml," but still get back "application/rdf+xml."

Answer (score 0):

SPARQL's `DESCRIBE` returns a single graph, but (if I remember correctly) TriX is for named graphs only. As a result I don't think TriX is considered a candidate for serialising the result of a such a query form (and similarly `CONSTRUCT`).

<s>(However I will check that)</s>

Having checked I see no mention of TriX in fuseki 2. TriX has never been widely used, so it's not entirely surprising.

Comment: Thanks. It looks like TriX doesn't actually require named graphs. The `<uri>` child of the `<graph>` element is optional. I'm able to upload a TriX file with no graph uri to the default graph in Fuseki.

Comment: Just updated answer. Any particular reason you want TriX?

Comment: It is not part of the server's offer as of the last Fuseki2 release. I'll add it for the next release.